# How can i overlay window subfile as400

Tags: window, ibm-midrange

this is the dds for  my screen:

```
<pre>
<code>
A                                      DSPSIZ(27 132 *DS4)  
A          R ASSUME                                         
A                                      ASSUME               
A                                      OVERLAY              
A                                  1  3' '                  
A          R SFLSEL                    SFL                  
A                                      SFLNXTCHG            
A            SEL            1A  B  4  2VALUES(' ' '1')      
A  43                                  DSPATR(ND)           
A  43                                  DSPATR(PR)           
A            FLDFET         8Y 0O  4  5EDTWRD('  /  /    ') 
A            FLDUSE        10A  O  4 37                     
A            FLDHOR         6Y 0O  4 28EDTWRD('  :  :  ')   
A            FLDFEC         8Y 0O  4 17EDTWRD('  /  /    ') 
A            FLDPER        20A  H                           
A          R CTRSEL                    SFLCTL(SFLSEL)       
A                                      CF03(03 'Salir')     
A                                      KEEP                 
A                                      OVERLAY              
A                                      SFLCSRRRN(&RRN)                      
A  80                                  SFLDSP                               
A  81                                  SFLDSPCTL                            
A  82                                  SFLINZ                               
A  83                                  SFLCLR                               
A  40                                  SFLEND(*MORE)                        
A                                      SFLSIZ(9999)                         
A                                      SFLPAG(0008)                         
A                                      WINDOW(*DFT 13 50)                   
A                                      WDWBORDER((*COLOR BLU))              
A                                      WDWTITLE((*TEXT 'Intro = Continuar - 
A                                        F3 = Salir') *CENTER *BOTTOM)      
A                                      WDWTITLE((*TEXT 'CONSULTAR REVISION- 
A                                      ES PASADAS') *CENTER)                
A            NBR            4S 0H      SFLRCDNBR(CURSOR)                    
A            RRN            5S 0H                                           
A                                  1  2'Op. 1=Seleccionar'                  
A                                      COLOR(BLU)                           
A                                  2  2'Op Fecha Trab  Fecha Gen  Hora    - 
A                                       Usuario      '                     
A                                  3  2'==================================-
A                                      =============='                     
A                                      COLOR(WHT)                          
A            MSGERR        30A  O  1 20COLOR(RED) 
</code>
</pre>
```

but for any razon always delete te background screen, i need to show the select but not delete the before screen.
i try several way to do that KEEP on control, ASSUME, OVERLAY, PUTOVR, RSTDSP *YES, and nothing work, please help me.

Comment: This DDS looks OK - there are small changes which can be made, but it should work already.  Could you edit your post to add the RPG?

Comment: Your `ASSUME` record format has the ASSUME keyword, but it also needs the KEEP keyword. It doesn't need the OVERLAY keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You might verify if the background screen was compiled with RSTDSP(*YES) or not. If not, try setting the attribute with the CHGDSPF command.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you require a separate record the uses `OVERLAY` and `ASSUME`. You do not have to display this record or reference it at all, it just has to be in the display file.

For example:

```
0017.70      A*--------------------------------------------------------------*

0017.80      A . . . . . . R BLKLN24                                             

0018.00      A . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  ASSUME                    

0018.10      A . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  OVERLAY
```

should work.